# My long haired cat keeps getting dirty - how do I keep her clean and how do I clean her all the time

Tags: cats, hygiene

How do I clean my long haired cat and keep her clean? I've bathed her and the next day she smells like urine all the time. How do I keep her clean? What can I do to help her? I don't think she is happy about this either.

Answer (score 7):

**The very first thing to do is take her to a vet to rule out any bladder, kidney, or incontinence issues.**

If there are no medical causes of her problems, the first thing I'd suggest from experience with long haired cats is taking a look at the fur on her back end. If she's constantly smelling of urine, chances are her fur is in the way when she urinates.

Some of the things you can do to mitigate problems with a long haired cat getting urine on her fur:

- Trim the fur around her butt. You don't need to shave, but making sure there's a clear area so when she urinates and defecates there's nothing in the way will help.
- Make sure you keep the litter box clean. She probably has tufts between her paw pads, and her belly fur could be long enough to drag through the litter as well. That will pick up damp litter and urine (clumping litter helps to mitigate this problem. So does replacing ordinary litter more often than you think you need to).
- Brush/comb her daily. This will help to remove anything that's been caught on her fur. As an added bonus, once she figures out this is pleasant time with her human, she'll want you to do it. It will also help prevent matting.

If that isn't enough you may need to observe her and see if she's playing in the litter box. If so, take a look at the answer to [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5581/should-i-keep-my-cat-from-playing-in-her-litter-box?rq=1).